# Multiplying org-mode check-boxes

Tags: org-mode

I have an org-mode document that looks like this

```
* Total Score

** First Part [2/3] * 4
- [X] Item 1
- [X] Item 2
- [ ] Item 3

** Second Part [2/3] * 3
- [X] Item 1
- [ ] Item 2
- [X] Item 3
```

Is there a way I can multiply the number of checked items in each headline by a number and accumulate the result on the parent headline?

```
* Total Score [14/21]

** First Part [2/3] * 4
- [X] Item 1
- [X] Item 2
- [ ] Item 3

** Second Part [2/3] * 3
- [X] Item 1
- [ ] Item 2
- [X] Item 3
```

If that's not possible, is there a way I can use these counts of checked-items as numbers in an org-table?

Comment: Possibly helpful: `(cdr (org-element-statistics-cookie-successor))` is the location of the next statistics cookie and `org-element-statistics-cookie-parser` can parse out the cookie.